Pass value out of iterator without stopping iteration
I have a function that parses an input string:
fn parse_input(s: &str) -> ((usize, usize), BTreeMap<(usize, usize), Tile>){
 let mut start: (usize, usize) = (0,0);
 let grid = s.split("\n").enumerate().flat_map(|(r,l)| {
     l.chars().enumerate().map(move |(col, c)| {
         let t = classify_tile(c);
         match t {
             Tile::Start => {
                  *start = (r, col);
                  ((r,col), t)
                 },
             _ => ((r,col), t) 
         }
     })
 }).collect::<BTreeMap<(usize, usize), Tile>>();
 (start, grid)
}

I basically want to capture the r and col value of the start tile (which is unique, only one occurrence). But currently if I try and modify the tuple inside the iterator I assume due to borrowing and scope reasons, the value doesn't get modified outside the iterator.
It is important the iterator finishes though.
An alternative solution would be to search for the start tile in the btreemap afterwards but I'm hoping for a more efficient solution.
Should I just do this as nested for loops? Is the iteration actually meaningfully more efficient here?
edit: classify_tile function returns the enum type. Start, Soil or Pipe.
The *start = (r,col) section is the bit that doesn't work. That was my attempt at solving it. Everything else works though.

You can do what you want, if you restructure your iterator a bit.

But let's first address what the issue is.
As a simpler example, let's count all uppercase letters (in a silly way):
let text = "Hello World";

let mut count = 0;

text.split_whitespace()
   .flat_map(|s| {
        s.chars().map(|c| {
            if c.is_uppercase() {
                count += 1;
            }
        })
    })
    .for_each(|_| {});

assert_eq!(count, 2);

If we try to compile this, we'll get the same issue you're getting:
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src\main.rs:85:13
   |
80 |       let mut count = 0;
   |           --------- variable defined here
...
84 |           .flat_map(|s| {
   |                       - inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
85 | /             s.chars().map(|c| {
86 | |                 if c.is_uppercase() {
87 | |                     count += 1;
   | |                     ----- variable captured here
88 | |                 }
89 | |             })
   | |______________^ returns a closure that contains a reference to a captured variable, which then escapes the closure body
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape

Why is that?
The closure given to map() requires mutably borrowing count, this in itself is perfectly fine.
The issue comes when we throw flat_map() into the mix. Since flat_map() potentially produces multiple iterators. Each of these produced iterators requires mutably borrowing count. This is of course not allowed, since we cannot mutably borrow anything more than once.

Overall, this is straight forward to resolve, you simply restructure the iterator:
text.split_whitespace()
    .flat_map(|s| s.chars())
    .map(|c| {
        if c.is_uppercase() {
            count += 1;
        }
    })
    .for_each(|_| {});

or
text.split_whitespace()
    .map(|s| s.chars())
    .flatten()
    .map(|c| {
        if c.is_uppercase() {
            count += 1;
        }
    })
    .for_each(|_| {});


Resolving this for your iterator, could look something like this:
let grid = s
    .split("\n")
    .enumerate()
    .flat_map(|(r, l)| {
        l.chars().enumerate().map(move |(col, c)| {
            let t = classify_tile(c);
            match t {
                Tile::Start => ((r, col), t),
                _ => ((r, col), t),
            }
        })
    })
    .inspect(|((r, col), t)| match t {
        Tile::Start => {
            start = (*r, *col);
        }
        _ => {}
    })
    .collect::<BTreeMap<(usize, usize), Tile>>();

or
let grid = s
    .split("\n")
    .enumerate()
    .flat_map(|(r, l)| l.chars().enumerate().map(move |(col, c)| ((r, col), c)))
    .map(|((r, col), c)| {
        let t = classify_tile(c);
        match t {
            Tile::Start => {
                start = (r, col);
                ((r, col), t)
            }
            _ => ((r, col), t),
        }
    })
    .collect::<BTreeMap<(usize, usize), Tile>>();

It can be written in multiple ways.

Awesome explanation thank you! I decided to go with the inspect option as the second solution it seems like it has to iterate through the data twice over? Which would make it analogous to just searching the btreemap after for the coordinate?

Both are effectively doing exactly the same. There is no "iterating twice" going on in either case. The main difference is of course, whether it's handled in map() or an additional inspect() is applied

Doesn't each map have to somehow process the data? So the second soln looks over the data multiple times? Or am I misunderstanding how iterators function

Maybe I'm misinterpreting what you imply with "iterating twice". Consider iter.map(a).map(b), then that doesn't process map 1 item 1, 2, 3, then map 2 item 1, 2, 3. It would process effectively as for x in ... then x = b(a(x))

@thefrollickingnerd map is lazy, so it doesn't iterate over the data at all. What it does is that it marks the data so that when (if) it gets iterated later on, it will be transformed on the fly. Multiple calls to map simply add their processing steps but they still don't iterate over the data. In your case, the only iteration is done by collect. Having multiple maps each adding a single processing step or having a single map that adds multiple processing steps is effectively equivalent.

Thanks for the explanations, really clarified a point of misunderstanding on my end.
